# How to use in-line expansion with execvp

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I am interested in, how can one accomplish in-line linux expansion with execvp in C.
I tried doing so with a backslashed apostrophe inside the one that indicates, that the following is a string, but failed. The code, that I run is as it follows:

```
static const char *datecmd[] = { "xsetroot", "-name", "$(date +'%T')", NULL };
execvp(((char **)arg->v)[0], (char **)arg->v);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-line expansion is a function of the shell, so you would need to run your command from inside of a shell, e.g.:

```
static const char *datecmd[] = { "bash", "-c",
                                 "xsetroot -name $(date +'%T')", NULL };
execvp(((char **)arg->v)[0], (char **)arg->v);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interested in [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).
Then you could also use [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to expand your thing, and later call [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) on its result.

BTW, for the particular expansion of `date +%T` you should read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and simply use a usual combination of [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). You don't need to run any `date` process (and you might avoid any globbing)