# Program C, mv: cannot stat No such file or directory

Tags: c, command, exec, mv, execv

I'm learning to fork and exec using c language, and trying to use mv. By moving all the files in the .png format located in the image folder to the photos folder using exec, but when moving it encountered the following problems:

```
mv: cannot stat 'image/*.png': No such file or directory
```

The following is a program that I have created

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *move[] = {"mv", "image/*.png", "photos", NULL};
        execv("/bin/mv", move);
}
```

When i try to move one file it works, but when moving multiple files with * it doesn't work. What is the solution to solve it?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use in-line expansion with execvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283522/how-to-use-in-line-expansion-with-execvp)

Comment: Glob expansion (`*` turning into list of filenames) is done by a shell, not by `mv`. What you are doing is trying to move one file which is literally named `image/*.png`, and it does not exist. Since `mv` knows nothing about special significance of `*`, you either have to exec `bash` and tell it to run `mv` (by executing `bash -c "mv image/*.png photos"`), or you need to do the work of finding the file list yourself (and executing `mv image/file1.png image/file2.png photos`)

Comment: ok thank you very much, is there a solution so that the character ```*``` can be recognized by mv and not changed to a list of filenames? @Amadan

Comment: I listed the two options. `mv` will never understand `*` as an expansion character. Run `bash`, which will expand `*` for you, or expand manually. Both options are described in the linked duplicate.